# background gradient opacity not working with styled components

Tags: css, typescript, next.js, styled-components

Hai I'm using styled components and I have the following code for my global style:

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    html{
        font-family: roboto;
        background: linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(137,255,255,0.5),rgba(161,252,143, 0.25), rgba(255,167,137, 1));
        height: 100vw;
        overflow: hidden;
    }`
export default GlobalStyle
```

For some reason the background is the correct gradient color but the opacity doesn't work for said gradeint.  I tried this and it works fine in normal html/css but for some reason not in my nextjs app.  Any idea why it's not working?

testing browser: firefox

Comment: Try `opacity: 0.5` it should work.

Comment: opacity: 0.5; doesn't work since each color of the gradient has a different opacity

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet may work for you.

There is an official nextjs example for styled-components here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-styled-components/pages/index.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const GlobalStyle = styled.html`
  font-family: roboto;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(137,255,255,0.5),rgba(161,252,143, 
  0.25), rgba(255,167,137, 1));
  height: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  `
export default function StyledHtml({ children}) {
   return (<GlobalStyle>
       {children}
   </GlobalStyle >);
}
```